# Use cookie-free domains - subdomain solution not working

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, subdomain

I'm trying to optimize an html webpage, and one of the suggestions from yslow is:

> Use cookie-free domains There are 11 components that are not
>   cookie-free

So I followed one of the standard solutions I've seen and created a subdomain static.mysite.com and put the images there.

But I'm still getting the exact same problem -- a cookie is still being delivered with each image, and same yslow message.

So how do I get this subdomain to be cookie free?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask such questions there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using subdomain for cookie-free delivery then your main page has to use www prefix.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The subdomain simply didn't work, so I used a different domain name and it solved the problem.

Answer (score -4):

When the browser makes a request for a static image and sends cookies together with the request, the server doesn't have any use for those cookies. So they only create network traffic for no good reason. You should make sure static components are requested with cookie-free requests. Create a subdomain and host all your static components there.

If your domain is www.example.org, you can host your static components on static.example.org. However, if you've already set cookies on the top-level domain example.org as opposed to www.example.org, then all the requests to static.example.org will include those cookies. In this case, you can buy a whole new domain, host your static components there, and keep this domain cookie-free. Yahoo! uses yimg.com, YouTube uses ytimg.com, Amazon uses images-amazon.com and so on.

Another benefit of hosting static components on a cookie-free domain is that some proxies might refuse to cache the components that are requested with cookies. On a related note, if you wonder if you should use example.org or www.example.org for your home page, consider the cookie impact. Omitting www leaves you no choice but to write cookies to *.example.org, so for performance reasons it's best to use the www subdomain and write the cookies to that subdomain.

Source - http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

**EDIT**

If you set your cookies on a top-level domain (e.g. yourwebsite.com) all of your sub-domains (e.g. static.yourwebsite.com) will also include the cookies that are set. Therefore, in this case, it is required that you use a separate domain name to deliver your static content if you want to use cookie-free domains. However, if you set your cookies on a www subdomain such as www.yourwebsite.com, you can create another subdomain (e.g. static.yourwebsite.com) to host all of your static files which will no longer result in any cookies being sent.

For Wordpress you can use this config:

```
define("WP_CONTENT_URL", "http://static.yourwebsite.com"); 
define("COOKIE_DOMAIN", "www.yourwebsite.com");
```

Details - https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-use-cookie-free-domains/

**EDIT 2**

You will need to move your static content over to the wp-content folder of your newly created subdomain!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your post does not address my specific question.

Comment: You will need to move your static content over to the wp-content folder of your newly created subdomain - have you done that?

Comment: Can you access the images using: http://static.yourwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/imagename.jpg ?